# Visual Studio new MVC View shortcut

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know if there is a command I can add a shortcut for adding a new MVC View (.cshtml) in VS 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None out the box but if you go to Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and search for add.view you can create your own keyboard shortcut.

Comment: That is the exact command i was looking for, not sure how I missed it, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have assigned Shift+Alt+V globally but when i select a folder in the Solution Explorer and fire the command nothing happens.

Comment: There were 3 Options for "ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Project.Add.View" in my solution. I experimented with them all until I found one that worked. I also selected "Solution Explorer" in the  "Use new shortcut in:" drop down.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option of `Add View` in the context menu , when you right click an action inside a controller which is a nice shortcut by itself. You can also make use of `Scaffolding` and generate the view automatically.

[image]